# shared library built with g++ compile is works and with automake compile can not be used

Tags: ffmpeg, g++, shared-libraries, automake

I'm building a shared libraries on CentOS 6.2. 
The shared library will be build have some cpp files,headers,c shared libraries
and ffmpeg.The shared library is used to convert videos. When i use the g++ compile like this:

```
g++    DataType.h    h264function.h  h264function.cpp videoconvert.h videoconvert.cpp      stdafx.h stdafx.cpp YV12toRGB.h YV12toRGB.cpp -lMPCtrl -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -   lhcnetsdk -lPlayCtrl -lpthread -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so
```

It can work properly,and the video can be converted as standard h264 coded.That seems the files used for building the library is

good.But when i use the autotools to make the library,it can not work correct.Here is my configure.in and Makefile.am:

Makefile.am:

```
prefix=/usr
lib_LTLIBRARIES=libhikvisiontranso.la

libhikvisiontranso_la_SOURCES=stdafx.h stdafx.cpp videoconvert.h videoconvert.cpp 
h264function.h h264function.cpp YV12toRGB.h YV12toRGB.cpp DataType.h 

libhikvisiontranso_la_LDFLAGS=-avoid-version -shared 
libhikvisiontranso_la_LIBADD=-lpthread -lMPCtrl -lhcnetsdk -lPlayCtrl -lavformat -    lavcodec -lavutil
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS= -I m4
```

configure.in:

```
#                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ([2.63])
AC_INIT([hikvisiontranso],[1.0], [songxiawuren@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([libhikvisiontranso.so],[1.0])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([DataType.h])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AT_INIT
# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([inttypes.h limits.h stddef.h stdint.h stdlib.h string.h])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_HEADER_STDBOOL
AC_C_INLINE
AC_TYPE_INT16_T
AC_TYPE_INT32_T
AC_TYPE_INT64_T
AC_TYPE_INT8_T
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
AC_TYPE_UINT16_T
AC_TYPE_UINT32_T
AC_TYPE_UINT64_T
AC_TYPE_UINT8_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The wrong output is :

```
SDL Init

init console=1

Output #0, avi, to '/home/ningge/Desktop/HaikangDvr.avi':

Stream #0.0: Invalid Codec type -1

Height = 576; Width = 704;totalfram=90000

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The right is:

```
SDL Init

init console=1

Output #0, avi, to '/home/ningge/Desktop/HaikangDvr.avi':

Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 704x576, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc

Height = 576; Width = 704;totalfram=90000

CSDLInit goOut
```

I hope someone can help me to find what's wrong with automake.

Comment: did you try to debug it?
the order of linking libraries may play a role, too (but I have no clue what is failing)